# Borderlands 2 Weapon Leveling

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm level 43 and I was farming Doc Mercy and he dropped a level 35 infinity. I'm already in TVHM. Is there anyway for me to get a leveled version without UVHM?

Answer (score 4):

You must complete the game on TVHM, and after that enemies (and the loot they drop) will be scaled to your level.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, enemies already level with you during TVHM, you don't have to complete the game on that mode first.